# I am trying to check collision in unity for my bullet and enemy, but it doesnt work

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I have this script attached to my bullet, which is currently just cube in 2d space. it has rigidbody2d, boxcollider and istrigger is checked.

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyBulletCollision : MonoBehaviour {

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collision coll)
{
    if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
        Destroy(coll.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

Enemy is also cube with BoxCollider, Rigidbody2d and istrigger checked.
Nothing just happens. i tried all kind of things, but none works. Kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Unity's 2D physics, you must use the corresponding 2D methods (all the same methods, just ending with "2D").  So instead of using `OnTriggerEnter`, you need to use [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html).

Comment: Ok that worked. Also needed to change Collision to Collider2d